# Add index to a new list

Tags: python-3.x, list, append

I want to append more than one index from '`my_list`' to '`item`'.
See code line 3, I wonder if there is a better/easier way to append more than one index at a time #to my new list??

```
my_list = ['1970', '43', '18', '336', '0', '0', '0', '0', '41', '0', '', '4']
item_list = []
item_list.append(my_list[3])
print(item_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `extend` and make it as list.

```
my_list = ['1970', '43', '18', '336', '0', '0', '0', '0', '41', '0', '', '4']
item_list = []
item_list.extend([my_list[3], my_list[2], my_list[6]])
print(item_list)
```

Comment: Great! I try to use extend.